# QTreeView scroll to current row after sort

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I'm adapting QT Creator [Basic Sort/Filter Model Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-basicsortfiltermodel-example.html) to work with my own source data (my movie library). That link shows what the example display looks like, and [here's a link to the relatively small amount of source code.](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/itemviews/basicsortfiltermodel?h=5.15) I don't really understand everything I'm doing, but mostly things have gone well until I hit this current problem...

> **How can I update the view so currently-selected row ALWAYS stays visible after changing sort order**?

I hope someone will tell me *exactly* what C++ code needs to added / modified in the actual example program. There's probably no point in posting links to QT documentation, or "similar" code doing much the same thing in other contexts, because I don't think I'll be able to understand how to adapt such information to my own needs.

I'm using latest QT Creator 6.0.2 running under latest Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon, but I'm not sure that makes any difference, and I don't know what if any other information might be relevant.

---

EDIT:
I assume the extra code to force "scroll to current selection after sort" logically fits in QT Creator source code file **examples/ widgets/ itemviews/ basicsortfiltermodel/ window.cpp**

I commented out line 122 in that file (suppress display of the "source" table, because I only want the "proxy" view). Other than that, the source file in my derived project is identical to the original [as held here on GitHub](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/itemviews/basicsortfiltermodel/window.cpp?h=5.15) (along with the header & main source for the example project, per my second link above).

Effectively, I'm asking for the smallest possible change *to the actual example project code* to ensure the currently selected line never disappears from view after sorting.

---

The exact example from QT documentation has less than a dozen rows of data, so *exact* control of display positioning doesn't matter much. But I'll normally have a *lot* of rows visible, and the currently selected row could appear at any position within the visible window. Sometimes, "current row" might not actually be visible *before* a sort, but I'd like it to always be visible *after*.

It might be asking a lot, but I'd be *seriously* impressed if anyone comes up with succinct code to ensure that *wherever possible*, the currently highlighted row ***stays in position (doesn't jump up or down)*** while the rows above and/or below change as a result of sorting.

Comment: Not the downvoter but... you really need to focus your question a bit more.  What have you tried?  Do you know how to get the currently selected index(es)?  Do you know how to ensure a particular row is visible?

Comment: @G.M.: Thanks for the response. Perhaps I should have been more exact than *I don't really understand everything I'm doing* above. In reality, The truth is I understand ***very little***. As I write this comment, I have no idea how to get the currently selected index(es), but I'm guessing I could probably figure that one out . It took me all afternoon yesterday to figure out how to get & set window size and position so I could "persist" them between multiple invocations of my program, but I got there in the end! This one has me beat so far, but I'll work through V.K.'s answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll to current row after sorting, then I would suggest doing the following four changes to your code.

You should implemented your own model by inheriting from `QStandardItemModel` and in this derived model class:

1. add a signal `sorted()` to your model class
2. override virtual method `sort()` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort)

```
void YourModel::sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder) override
{
    QStadardItemModel::sort(column, order);
    emit sorted(); // this is the signal you added
}
```

3. Then create a method which will access the tree view and would do this:

```
void scrollAfterSort()
{
   treeView->scrollTo(treeView->currentIndex());
}
```

4. Connect `YourModel::sorted()` signal to this `scrollAfterSort()` method.

Comment: I won't be able to work through this until tomorrow, but a brief glance suggests this will sort me out. Even if it doesn't, thank you very much for responding! I will "accept" if I can successfully implement this within 24 hours!

Comment: OK. I have not tested it, of course, because I do not have your code. If you have any issue, let me know here in comments, I hope I will be able to help you.

Comment: Actually, I *don't* know how to use this information! I haven't "implemented my own model" (which I don't understand in this context anyway). I happen to have written my own class to remember & restore window geometry, but other than that, there's only the "Window" class as already defined in the example program. Within which I commented out mainLayout->addWidget(sourceGroupBox) so only the tableView of the proxyGroupBox gets shown. All I changed is the number & names of columns in createMailModel(), which I also extended to load my own data from a file. But it's basically the example code.

Comment: I assume the required code goes in examples/widgets/ itemviews/ basicsortfiltermodel/ window.cpp from the GitHub link in my question, and that where you say **treeView->scrollTo** to force the display scroll, that's specifically the original class **proxyView**. Note that I commented out line 122 **mainLayout->addWidget(sourceGroupBox);** because I only want the lower table display, but other than that I've barely touched the code of that source file. I don't see where or how to add the lines you've outlined above, but reference to specific line numbers in the source & header files might help

Comment: Well, you should implement your own model, if you want this non-standard behavior. Actually it will be very easy, inherit your own model from `QStandardItemModel` and override the `sort()` method as I suggested. And add that `sorted()` signal. That's all. (I updated the text of my answer a bit to reflect this.)

Comment: I understand how to write my own classes in C++, and *very* occasionally I've managed to create a "derived" class. But I've no idea how to "implement my own model" in the context of a QT program, and I have only limited understanding of windows message processing (the syntax & parameters for "connect" in QT baffle me). Basically, at this stage in the game it's no good telling me to implement classes and override methods, because I haven't got a clue how to do such things in this context. Maybe I need to ask on some other site more geared up to complete noobs.

Comment: It's irrelevant that I'm writing my own program *based* on QT's **basicsortfiltermodel** example. All I really want right now is the exact code changes to **window.cpp / window.h** which would produce the desired behaviour in the example program itself. I might be able to figure out for myself how to "re-align" the display, if someone could just show me how to pass program control to a function of my own immediately after the existing code has performed the sort operation (because I the user clicked on one of the column labels). I simply don't know how to make my function get called.

Comment: By implementing your own model, I mean that you should write a derived class which would inherit from `QStandardItemModel` and declare the signal and override one virtual method. If you have no idea how to do it, then I am afraid we both are wasting our time here. You should first learn the basics and then go for more complicated stuff. I do not want to be unhelpful, but StackOverflow is not here to teach clueless noobs the very basics of their craft. Sorry :)

Comment: Btw. I guess that is the reason why someone gave you minus points. You came to StackOverflow saying "I want something but I have no idea what I am doing". Answers to such requests can only hardly bring any benefit to others. So that's why you got the minus.

Comment: How on earth am I expected to *learn* what I'm supposed to be doing, if no-one will help me by giving me ***example code***. I've been looking at mountains of QT documentation for days now, but I don't understand much at all. And I more than suspect that at least *part* of my problem is that things have changed over time. It's already clear to me there are at least two significantly different ways of defining the links between "mouse / keyboard events" and "service routines" under QT, but I don't understand either the differences ***or*** the similarities there.

Comment: I'd have though there should be a LOT of people who'd like to know how to implement this functionality in the actual QT training example. Just because I'm now retired and therefore not really able or willing to commit vast amounts of time and money to following a proper training course shouldn't imply mine isn't a "typical" thing for noobs to be interested in.

Comment: Well, clearly I'd be wasting my time arguing, so I won't. I'm afraid I felt obliged to cancel my upvote, since you don't really seem to have helped me with my actual technical problem. But thank you for responding at all. At least it's better than the response I got on SO AskUbuntu - when I posted much the same question there, I admitted I'd already asked here. On the AskUbuntu version, I never mentioned that I was using Mint, because that seemed irrelevant, But even though they've accepted hundreds of questions flagged "QT", mine is Off Topic - apparently because someone realised I'm on Mint.

Comment: Sorry about the less-than-warm welcome on Ask Ubuntu. You're question was off-topic because Mint is [off-topic on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Also, people don't like it when people repost the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites, so you got downvoted. Please don't take it personally. Questions about Mint are fine on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), though. But re-posting the exact same question is frowned upon. Moreover, until you learn the basics, you won't be very successful with figuring this out. There are plenty of free tutorials online.

Comment: @cocomac: I've been looking at online tutorials for months now (text-only, and YouTube videos). I would have dsaid I was a pretty experienced programmer, having been earned my living writing hi-performance C++ programs for decades until I retired a few years back. But I only ever linked to standard C libraries, and in the absence of *interactive* feedback & guidance, the learning curve for a behemoth like QT is simply too steep for me. I've spent most of this afternoon successfully implementing **myQTreeView** for the **proxyView** object in the example...

Comment: ...but I've no idea why **myQTreeView::selectionChanged()** only seems to get called *sometimes* when I click on the column headers (not always). And although the line **scrollTo(currentIndex())** compiles in my version, it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm floundering, for lack of what I assume should be some trivial guidance.